# How do I get logout to work on RubyCAS-Server?

Tags: ruby, single-sign-on, cas

I have installed and setup RubyCAS-Server and RubyCAS-Client on my machine. Login works perfectly but when I try to logout I get this error message from the RubyCAS-Server:

```
Camping Problem!

CASServer::Controllers::Logout.GET

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `casserver_pgt` WHERE (username = 'lgs') :
```

I am using version 0.6 of the gem. Looking at the migrations in the RubyCAS-Server it looks like there shouldn't be a username column in that table at all.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there's a bug in the 0.6 version of the gem (possibly coinciding with change made to finders in Rails 2.1) as detailed in this [bug ticket](http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-server/issues/detail?id=48).  In the meantime, you could try [installing from the source tree](http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-server/source/checkout).

Comment: Thanks - installing from the source tree (revision 312) works perfectly. Looking forward to 0.7.

Answer (score 0):

In case of the ruby CAS there are two kinds of session :

(1). The application session.

(2). The Single sign on (SSO) session.

you can use sinatra-session gem for managing the application session and just use *session_end!* helper method to destroy the application session. For destroying the SSO session unset the *session[:cas_ticket]* parameter in logout route.

example:

In case of the Sinatra: 
 `get '/logout' do 
            session_end!                      # provided by sinatra-session gem
            session[:cas_ticket] = nil        # session variable set by CAS server
          end`